# When I try to rig, I keep getting the message, "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones." What do I do?

Tags: mesh, rigging, error

So, I am trying to rig with automatic weights to this mesh and again I kept getting that error message. I have tried two things already I have Decimated the Mesh and have merged by distance and I don't know what to do.
[[image: This is the mesh I am talking about.1]

Comment: Hello, maybe your mesh is too dense? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I am trying to share my file but it says it is to big.

Comment: Lots of questions and answers about that if you bother to search here for them!  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275874/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones-multiple-sol?rq=1  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128295/rigging-doesnt-work-bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-mo?rq=1  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69892/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones-error-message?rq=1

Comment: or use another platform like workupload

Comment: As @JohnEason said, there are lots of solutions already here. Please use the search before asking a question, as it saves us time from writing an answer that already exists and it also might help you faster to check if they solve your issue rather than waiting until someone comes up with an answer to this question.

Comment: Hello, Booga, welcome to BSE. There are so many, I think it's fair for us to **know** you have explored the solutions suggested in the links above in the commentary, before posting your own version of the question. That may be the case. If so, you can edit to explain that the others haven;t worked for you, and we can re-open your post.